# How to perform git operations for git sub module?

Tags: git

I am new to git and downloaded the Nuttx from git repo as per the guidelines given in the nutt.org.

Nuttx code has config directory as a submodule ( I don't know what a git submodule is).

Now I added/modified files within this directory and asked for `git status`.

I got the following error:

```
nw@kkrishna:~/nuttx/nuttx$ git add configs/ak1w/src/ak1w_nsh.c
fatal: Path 'configs/ak1w/src/ak1w_nsh.c' is in submodule 'configs'
```

Now, I want to know how to track changes in git sub module?

Further, how can I do all the operations ( git add, git commit & push for the changes within submodule)

Comment: You are supposed to clone the `configs` submodule before add/changing anything in it. Remove everything from `configs` folder and try the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git submodule is a git repository in itself which need to cloned separately or the parent repository should be cloned recursively.

Try one of the following:

```
cd <repository folder>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Or clone the repository recursively:

```
git clone --recursive <repo path>
```